# Mongodb database design for location queries

Tags: mongodb, database

I am developing an app and I've chosen mongodb as the database mainly because of its flexibility and the ability to query geospatial data. But I tend to be a bit old school concerning the design (read 'relational database') and I'd like a few hints on how to design my database so it best fits my need.

I have a User model, and let's say an Object item. Each user has a location (which can change rapidly over the time). The Object items also have a location and belongs to a User.

For now I kinda developed my database like I'd do it in MySql:

- A User table with an array of Object ID
- an Object table with a reference to the owner (user) ID.

Since I will need to make frequent queries on the location of each model and make some range query (which objects are closer than 100m to this user, etc.), is this a good design? My main concern is the location query. I know I can put an index on the location, but I do not want to put two index location on the User and the Object array of the user on the same table.

Another feature is that I will surely be doing some sharding on my database, and according from what I read on mongodb, I think I'll make the sharding on the location index (mostly the user).

Does that make sense or should I actually just go with the one-size-fits-all approach? Or do you have another design in mind that would be better?

Thanks.

Comment: Since both change frequently, I would go for having separated collections and having a reference of the user in the object documents. It will be then super easy to update those objects, super easy to query them (by userId and geoloc). Having them splitted will let you update them a frequently without degrading performances ! If you don't know this guide, I would advice you to read it : https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-one-relationships-between-documents/

Comment: I would like to add that it also depends on your use case, but from what I understood, I doubt that you want to return the user document each time you are looking objects, so it is not relevant to embed objects in the user in this case

Answer (score 0):

As per my opinion:

**Step 1:** You can use three different collections. First one for the Users and second will be Locations and last will be ITEMS(Along with user ID).

**Step 2:**  In your location collection you can save both of the coordinates of the location distinguished by two different types. For example, for user location you can set type as "USER_LOC" and for Object(Item) location you can set type as "ITEM_LOC" along with USER ID and ITEM ID ().

**Step 3:** As if ITEM and USERS locations are moving so you can save both the(user and item) coordinates in your location collection.

**Step 4:** You can save last coordinates of item and users in their respective collections itself.

**Step: 5** As per your query if you want to fetch items which are near to user in X meter distance so you can filter location collection for ITEM type only and you have last coordinates of the user in USER collection itself. So you can find List of items which are near to user current location within a specific distance.

This is just my opinion. Thanks.